# $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ for n>1, in Gravity , QFT, CFT,

Tags: string-theory, quantum-information, quantum-gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

Edited:
I'm searching for some application of this manifold in CFT $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ for n>1.

However, I need some examples of this kind of manifold in QFT, CFT, Gravity, etc. of any power of $n\geq2$.
I really appreciate that if someone helps me for this or any useful hint.

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: I don't really understand what is the question here.

Comment: @Qmechanic, At least answer one of them!

Comment: @Blazej I edited. I hope it helps.

Comment: Virtually any paper on AdS/CFT. Also, read https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the boundary of $AdS_{n+1}$. in the global coordinate.